# How to setup Eclipse to connect to a mobile device (generate crash logs regarding android/ios app crashes)

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, logging, crash

I've searched online about getting crash logs from android and/or ios devices but could not find anything. I am testing an external app atm and have solid steps to reproduce a crash. Though, I can get a crash log/dump for the developer by using Eclipse... any guides on how to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to see log calls and other info, you have to enable Debug Mode in your device.
You also need a specific driver to use your device with ADT. If you don't have that driver you can download a generic one from google in SDK Manager > Extras.

But be aware that "commercial" apps (downloaded from Google Play) are not debuggable,
or at least should not be.

Answer (score 0):

First install the driver software for your mobile. Enable your debugging mode in your mobile. Go to DDMS->windows->show view click device. Here u can able to know wether ur device is connected or not.